# In a macOS Cocoa Application, I am implementing a simple glowing red dot icon for when activity is in progress. How can I make it more fluid?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, catransition

I am implementing the glowing red button as a subclass of NSImageView. You can see my code [here](https://gist.github.com/alfonsotesauro/efcb8007b09e51660cb52917924f5ee0).

When a background activity is in progress, the red circle image does not glow fluidly as it should. However, it starts to glow by the end of  the background process.

Can anybody give me any suggestions by looking at my code ?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, your red button doesn’t glow when you call it from a background thread.

Because you can not update UI from background thread. 
You may have two options here :

1. Do what you want to do with your `GlowingImageView` instance in main thread by using `DispatchQueue.main.async`
2. Implement your animation code on main thread! Which is **crazy**! And I am not recommending this!

Comment: Sorry, but if you look at the code I have provided, I am not calling from a background thread. My subclass is totally independent and it glows without any code to be added since its animating bool var is set to true when the object is created. I just create an instance of that class in interface builder. I know very well that UI code must not be called in a background thread.

Comment: @AlfonsoTesauro Ok, looks like I have not understood you correctly. May I suggest to paraphrase your question? Good luck